# Android app goes back to MainActivity While clicking Adapter Element?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, webview

I am working on an android app. I have made a recyclerview and adapter to hold logos, titles and names. 
On clicking on an element of adapter holder i have want to open a website link and i have used Intent for that bust when i click on any element the app goes back to main screen. below is the code of Adapter and Intent which i am using for opening webview activity for links.
`@NonNull`
    @Override
    public WaterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.water_single_view, parent, false);
        WaterViewHolder waterViewHolder = new WaterViewHolder(view);
        return waterViewHolder;
    }

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WaterViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.logo_iv.setImageResource(logoArray[position]);
    holder.titleName_tv.setText(titleArray[position]);
    holder.CompleteName_tv.setText(nameArray[position]);
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent wenIntent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            wenIntent.putExtra("url", urlArray[position]);
            context.startActivity(wenIntent);

            String ref = sharedPreferences.getString(titleArray[position], "");
            OpenDialog(urlArray[position], titleArray[position], ref);
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the code for Activity which is showing Recyclerview

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_water);

```
    int[] logoArray = {R.drawable.wasa_faisalabad, R.drawable.wasa_gujranwala, R.drawable.wasa_hydrabad
            , R.drawable.wasa_lahore, R.drawable.kwsb, R.drawable.wasa_multan, R.drawable.wasa_rawalpindi};

    String[] titleNameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.water_title);

    String[] nameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.water_name);

    String[] urlArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.water_url);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.water_rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    WaterAdapter waterAdapter = new WaterAdapter(logoArray, titleNameArray, nameArray, urlArray, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(waterAdapter);
}
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.Why when on clicking any element it takes me to main screen. 
Looking for your response
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some logs?

Comment: 2019-11-25 20:40:38.153 15033-15033/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15033
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Edit the answer and post this logs there instead of posting in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
    android:name=".WebViewActivity"
    android:label="WebViewActivity" >
   </activity>
```

You have not added the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, hence the app is crashing.